# I have had this knife for over 60 years and I would like to know what these Kanji mean

Tags: kanji, writing-identification

[image]

Here is a photo of the knife I have had for 60 years.

Comment: きり安 ? cheap cut? easy to cut? i don't know about last kanji.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't really look like Japanese...

Comment: @RyotaDiav Absolutely no.

Answer (score 1):

If I can be brutally honest, this doesn't look authentic at all. My guess is that this is a fake Japanese marking done by a westerner. The first letter is "き" and that's a hiragana letter, but the font is so cheap, childish, and unprofessional. The next letter is a made-up kanji, and the last symbol in the box at the bottom is probably an imitation of a stamp.

For your reference, below is a real professional marking on a knife. You can clearly see the difference in quality and craftsmanship:

[image]

Comment: I know that this inscription wasn't done professionally as the knife owner obviously inscribed it himself.  I am just trying to find out what it means in Kanji, Hiragana, etc.

Comment: OK, thanks. In that case I stand by with my original guess that it is fake Japanese. That is, he copied the style of strokes and such to make it like kanji, but they are not real kanjis. There's no meaning.

Comment: It just occurred to me that maybe he's trying to write "Cian," which I understand to be a common Irish name. It kind of looks a little like き安.